# Office 365proplus deployment error, Server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

I hope you can help me. I purchased Office 365 proplus licenses and I'm having difficulties deploying it into our Server 2012R2.

**Background info:**
Users log into Server 2012R2 with Remote desktop and access Office programs within their user profiles. Office 365 must be installed for each user. I have to use the deployment tool because I install Office 365 ProPlus on a computer configured as a Remote Desktop Session Host server. So I have to use the **SharedComputerLicensing setting** to enable shared computer activation, which is required to use Office 365 ProPlus on a shared computer.Previous installation of Office 2007 enterprise 32bit was uninstalled recently. I'm trying to install Office 365 64bit. There are no more Office programs installed on the server.

**The problem:**
I downloaded Office 2016 deplyoment tool and followed online instructions. I created two different XML files, one for software download and one for configuration. However I keep getting errors and I'm unable to install the software. I get different errors for downloading and configuration. I tried downloading the source files from another computer and copied it to the server but the errors remain.

**XML files (screenshot):**
[Image 1 - XML files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Wni.png)

**Errors I'm getting:**
[Image 2 - Deployment errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4y3s.png)

Really would appreciate the help. It's driving me nuts.

Cheers
Jako

Comment: Can you just post the error messages please, no one is going to just download a zip from dropbox.

Comment: Hey. Sry about that. I added the screenshots.

Comment: You can't run the /configure portion until after you run the /download.  How much space do you have?  Have you tried from a different location to ensure it's not network quality?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to sort it out by cleaning up old files one by one including in the registry and after that I was able to download the source files. And I started from the scratch by using a nice tool - officedev.github.io/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/…?